# How can I change the name of the tick marks in a scatterplot with ggplot in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatter-plot, axis-labels

In my scatterplot, I would like to replace the names of the tick marks (1 to 8) with the corresponding CEFR levels (A1.1 to B2.2) without changing the data frame.

```
1 = A1.1,
2 = A1.2,
3 = A2.1,
4 = A2.2,
5 = B1.1,
6 = B1.2,
7 = B2.1,
8 = B2.2
```

My code:

```
ggplot(data =  doppelratings1_mit_ID,
  aes(x = R1 , y = R2)) +
  geom_jitter(shape=1, width = 0.05, height = 0.15) + 
  geom_smooth() +
  xlab("Rater 1") +
  ylab("Rater 2") +
  ggtitle("Korrelation zwischen Rater 1 und 2", paste("n = 19 Texte ")) +
  theme_bw(12)+
  geom_abline(intercept = 0, slope = 1)
```

I tried

```
CEFR <- c("A1.2", "A2.2", "B1.2")
```

And then

```
+ scale_x_discrete(labels= CEFR)
```

but then the tick marks disappeared.

Thanks for your help!

See my scatter plot:

[image: Correlation between two Raters]

Comment: I suspect your x-axis is numeric, not categorical, so `scale_x_discrete()` would throw things out of sync. Try `+ scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(1, 8), labels = c("A1.1", "A1.2", ...))` instead?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I am sure the scales are discrete, because the CEFR levels are categories (levels of language proficiency).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your plot definition:

```
tick_names <- c('A1.1', 'A1.2', ..., 'B2.2')

ggplot() + 
  ... +
scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:8, labels = tick_names, limits = c(1, 8)) +
scale_y_continuous(breaks = 1:8, labels = tick_names, limits = c(1, 8))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I managed to display the scatter plot with slight changes of your code, as the scale is discrete indeed.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to display the scatter plot with the following code:

```
tick_names <- c("A1.1", "A1.2", "A2.1", "A2.2", "B1.1", "B1.2", "B2.1", "B2.2")
tick_names_x <- c("A1.1", "A1.2", "A2.1", "A2.2", "B1.1", "B1.2", "B2.1")

ggplot(data =  doppelratings1_mit_ID,
aes(x = R1 , y = R2)) +
geom_jitter(shape=1, width = 0.05, height = 0.15) + 
geom_smooth() +
xlab("Rater 1") +
ylab("Rater 2") +
ggtitle("Korrelation zwischen Rater 1 und 2", paste("n = 19 Texte ")) +
theme_bw(12)+
geom_abline(intercept = 0, slope = 1) +
scale_y_discrete(breaks = 1:8, labels = tick_names, limits = c(1:8)) +
scale_x_discrete(breaks = 1:7, labels = tick_names_x, limits = c(1: 7))
```

Thanks for you help!
See the image: [correlation between two raters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uPzHd.png)